# Downgrade AWS RDS MySQL 8.0.29 to 8.0.28 lower version

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I know AWS do not support downgrades in the RDS UI or with CLI, however I have been told that I can downgrade from the deprecated MySQL 8.0.29 to 8.0.28 using the AWS Database Migration Service.

I have Googled everywhere but can't find any help on this, and I'm still waiting for Amazon to tell me.

Does anybody know how to do this (step by step instructions would help) or if there is another way?

Comment: according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/Welcome.html you should create a new MySQL database with verison 8.0.28, then configure in AWS Database Migration Service to replicate data from your older database to the new database.

Comment: I know you can replicate (thus I mentioned Database Migration Service), it's just finding instructions how to do it, thus I asked if anybody knew of a guide.